# Unable to locate a file path

Tags: macos, filesystems, bitdefender

I have Bitdefender Antivirus installed. I attempted to download and install a Monero wallet. The antivirus program identified 4 items of malware. It was able to delete two of the items, but two must be manually removed. I tried clicking the blue button in the picture below to be taken to the path, but nothing happened. All I have to go on is the /dev/fd/32 and /dev/fd/35 file path using MacOS. I do not know how to do so. How can I track down the file path so that I might delete these two?

[image: Bitdefender System Scan]

Answer (score 0):

Reboot the Mac & re-run BitDefender.

/dev/fd/ is a temporary mount-point not a 'real' folder & this location would probably have gone by the time you unmounted the disk image.

It shouldn't in any case survive through a reboot, but re-scanning will make sure it's not a persistent structure being re-installed by any surviving malware process.